# how to synchronize sqlite database with Remote server database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization

I have a `Sqlite` database and a `Remote` database. I am trying to use the `Base Sync adapter` framework. I am trying to synchronize with the Xampp database.So I don't want to use any accounts authorization. I am actually not clear about what to do. Till now I have done the following:

```
       public syncad(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
        ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HttpClient  httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost  httppost2 = new HttpPost("myurl/myphp.php");
      try
       {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair>  nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TaskId","1"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("head","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("des","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateone","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("datetwo","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeone","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timetwo","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("r","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("s","a"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stat","a"));

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"in"+phno.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status",phno.getText().toString()));
            //String f=phno.getText().toString();
            //Log.w("communityfragment",f.toString());
            /*SharedPreferences prefs=getActivity().getPreferences(0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edt=prefs.edit();

            edt.putString("mynumber",f);
            edt.commit();

            */
             Log.i("task from namevaluepairs",""+nameValuePairs.toString());
             httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response1 = null;
            response1 = httpclient2.execute(httppost2);
       }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

I want to start synchronizing on a Button click in an activity. Is it possible and what I am doing is correct/

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no errors but its not working either.I have just used a MainActivity.class and the above mentioned code in another class

Comment: Did you check your DDMS ?